# still unable to setup path environment variable for android view client

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

does not show the AndroidViewClient folder in the installed directory

so unable to locate it, but able to see com-dtmilano and folders after that. but not able to see src and AndroidViewClient folder.

Comment: Can you describe the previous steps you did in detail?

Comment: @dtmilano I have somehow figured that to get it working,since androidviewclient can be used independently with a python interpreter. However the actual issue now is how do I test with androidviewclient and culebra. I have gone through your blog but I seem lost.

Comment: The [blog](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com) and the [wiki](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki) should cover all the aspects. If you can't find something don't hesitate to ask here.